# Oracle Linux 7 repository to update channels in Spacewalk

Tags: linux

I've been deploying VMs with kickstart files and OSes like CentOS7 and Oracle Linux 7 in Spacewalk, I even update the VM with a yum update in the post installation kickstart script, which is amazingly cool. After installation though, it doesn't really keep up to date with the latest version of the operating system, I'd have to download and upload the .ISO to Spacewalk every time an update comes around or do a yum update on the VM itself. Then I found out you can link and schedule an OS repository. I already have a setup of this kind for CentOS7 in Spacewalk.

This works for me:

- [CentOS7 repository for spacewalk channel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCgUA.png)
- [The link to the CentOS7 repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/)

However, I haven't found any public repos for OL7. Does this kind of repo simply not exist for Oracle Linux 7?

Also, is there perhaps a better solution to this problem? I'm planning on using Puppet with this setup for the software aspect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The git tag should not be used for items that merely involve some git repository, and the oracle tag should not be used for questions that are not about ORDBMS. I'm not really sure which tags are appropriate here (if any ... I see 3 close votes :-) ) but I'll strip off git and oracle tags.

Comment: @torek I initially wanted to use the Spacewalk and Oracle-Linux-7 tags but wasn't allowed to do so. :)

Answer (score 0):

From: Oracle® Linux Administrator's Guide for Release 7

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/ol7-downloading-yum-repo.html

2.3 Downloading the Oracle Linux Yum Server Repository Files

Note
The following procedure assumes that yum on your system is configured to expect to find repository files in the default /etc/yum.repos.d directory.

To download the Oracle Linux Yum Server repository configuration file:

As root, change directory to /etc/yum.repos.d.

## cd /etc/yum.repos.d

Use the wget utility to download the repository configuration file that is appropriate for your system.

## wget http://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-release.repo

For Oracle Linux 7, enter:

## wget http://yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol7.repo

The /etc/yum.repos.d directory is updated with the repository configuration file, in this example, public-yum-ol7.repo.

You can enable or disable repositories in the file by setting the value of the enabled directive to 1 or 0 as required.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides publicly accessible yum repos at yum.oracle.com. They even have their own build of Spacewalk available to customers.

Further, I added ULN support to Spacewalk a while ago, so you can configure it to sync content from ULN if you're a customer. See the Oracle Spacewalk Client Life Cycle Guide for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E71078/html/swk24-crreposwc.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright REW and Djelibeybi both gave me good answers, instead of using the repo file though I opten to fully use Spacewalk and use the links *in* the repo file to update the channel. In hindsight I can't believe I didn't come up with this sooner because I knew of the yum public file.

- [The link to repo file was wrong,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Uqk.png)
- [I instead should have just used the links in the repo file to create multiple Spacewalk Channel repositories.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5k1J.png)

Thank you all, I'm very happy with this solution.